# How to parse a simple quoted string (handling escapes)

Tags: python

*Note: this should be REALLY simple, I know. It's not. Or I'm dumb. But I tried hard.*

What I want to do is simple. I have a string, there are strings inside it, separated with `,`, quoted with `'`. I want to parse them. Consider the presence of `\'`s and `\\`s.

I want to do in the most simple, elegant and coincise way, obviously.

Now, on to some failed tries:

- "I know, I'll use `json`!" No. JSON uses `"`. Too bad.
- Mmmh, a regex? This looks like looking for trouble, but... Oh God my eyes those regexes I got from the Internet! At least do they... Nope, no support of escapes.
- `shlex`! The Python standard library always has a solution! See below my failed attempt.
- Current status: sobbing, writing a parser.

Test input: `'xx\'x,x\\x"xx\\\'\\',1,2,'xx\'x\''`
Test output: `xx'x,x\x"xx\'\`, `1`, `2`, `xx'x'`

```
def split(s):
    import shlex
    lex = shlex.shlex(s, posix=True)
    lex.whitespace = ','
    lex.whitespace_split = True
    lex.commenters = ''
    return list(lex)
```

Comment: Doesn't the built-in `split()` function already do what you need, without you having to overwrite it?  http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: @msturdy Not if there are commas in his nested strings.

Comment: No, it does not handle quotations and escapes. See the updated test case.

Comment: ah, you updated now.. what about the csv library?

Comment: I've been looking into it for a while now, it seems promising, but surely not out-of-the-box. I'll let you know if I get it to work.

Comment: If you want to ease your regex-related work, this could prove useful: https://www.debuggex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made it. I've looked into `csv` before but I needed to customize it heavily. Here is the function

```
def parse_quoted_strings_list(s):
    import csv
    return next(csv.reader([s],
        skipinitialspace=True,
        quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,
        escapechar='\\',
        doublequote=False,
        quotechar="'"))
```

And here are the tests

```
>>> test = r"""'xx\'x,x\\x"xx\\\'\\',1,2,'xx\'x\''"""
>>> map(print, parse_quoted_strings_list(test))
xx'x,x\x"xx\'\
1.0
2.0
xx'x'
```